# "Incorret syntax near..." error when running SQL file using SQLCMD

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I have this command that found on the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180944.aspx). but it throws syntax error. 
Is there any keywords that i missed? I have read many forums but couldn't find the solution. I also visit guide on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180944.aspx). but nothings happen.

```
 sqlcmd -S SERVER\SQL2008R2 -i sqlfile.sql
```

[image: Screenshot of SQLCMD error]

Comment: The SQL in `sqlfile.sql` has a syntax error within. Your `sqlcmd` call looks fine.

Comment: that script was auto generated.. using generate script

Comment: run the file directly in Management Studio, you should get the same error.

Comment: the reason i use sqlcmd 'coz that file is too heavy to open on management  studio.. i shows `HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component` because it's to heavy

Comment: see my aswer below. Try that first, to prove it is the T-SQL and not SQLCMD. P.S. What do you mean by "too heavy"? I'm assuming the file is just large? The error message suggests the error is on line 1, so you could just grab the first batch and run that in SSMS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run this on `Command Prompt` and not inside `sqlcmd`:

`sqlcmd -S SERVER\SQL2008R2 -U UserName -P Password -i sqlfile.sql`

i.e. `C:\>sqlcmd -S SERVER\SQL2008R2 -U UserName -P Password -i sqlfile.sql`

Comment: you nailed it @Vishal Garjjar.. my scripts is now running. I guess there's another syntax if i really want to execute the script inside the `sqlcmd`

Answer (score 0):

Your `sqlcmd` looks fine.

The error message relates to the SQL within `sqlfile.sql`!

To prove the point, change the contents of the file to something really simple e.g.

```
SELECT 'Success!' As result
```

Then run the `sqlcmd` command again.

Comment: tnx @gvee.. i will try to check my script.

Comment: the problem is not the script but the environment on where should i run the command. @Vishal Gajjar 's answer catched it. :)

Comment: Aha - I did not spot that subtlety!

Answer (score -1):

This can be caused by a single quote in block comments within a TSQL statement in the SQLCMD Editor.  This may be a bug because the problem does not occur with the normal SQL Editor

To confirm this, in SSMS, click on New Query to open the SQL Editor.
Type
:CONNECT Hostname\SQLInstance
replacing Hostname\SQLInstance with your values for a named instance or just your Hostname if you a using a default SQLInstance.

Switch to SQLCMD mode by clicking on the Query menu and selecting SQLCMD mode.

You should see the :CONNECT text you entered change to a grey background.

This confirms you are now using the SQLCMD editor/parser.

Paste the following below the :CONNECT statement, replacing  with a valid db name to which you have appropriate permissions.

USE 
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].vw_Test AS
/*/*/* 
   Let's test use of single quote in block comments.
*/*/*/ 
SELECT 1 + 1 AS SimpleSum;
GO
PRINT 'View vw_Test created'

Now, try compiling the view e.g. by clicking the F5 key.  You will get an error message similar to this.

Connecting to ...
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure vw_Test, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
Disconnecting connection from ...

If you remove the single quote by changing: 
Let's test 
to 
Lets test

..you get a healthy message:

Connecting to ...
View vw_Test created
Disconnecting connection from ...

When you are using sqlcmd to run multiple external sql files, you may also encounter the same problem i.e. the separate files compile without problem in SSMS but when invoked from sqlcmd...it complains.